# Angular 2 - NgForm with pattern issue

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

everyone ! The pattern itself works. I extracted from http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?regexp_id=409 and tested using https://regex101.com/ with the data: `02/02/2012` and many others.

Maybe I'm not using properly it ?

```
<form class="searchBlock" [ngFormModel]="formSearch">
   <input type="text" ngControl="frmDateFrom">
</form>
<span>{{formSearch.valid | json}}</span>


import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, Control, ControlGroup, Validators} from 'angular2/common';
export class MyComponent {
  formSearch: ControlGroup;
  frmDateFrom: Control;
  constructor(private builder: FormBuilder) {
        this.frmDateFrom = new Control('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$")]));
        this.formSearch = builder.group({
        frmDateFrom: this.frmDateFrom
    });
  }
}
```

No matter what is the value, formSearch.valid always will show me false. What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use a simple regex like `"^[a-z]$"` it's working fine, therefore I'd assume it has to be the regex that causes the issues.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/J3MBFbeO2DLpO0AuUvKv?p=preview)

I'm pretty sure the problem is caused by the backslashes which need to be escapted. Just change any `\` to `\\`